# Convert dataframe: several columns to single by order

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.1.1 and dataframe. Here is my input dataframe:

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+
| key|parameter|reference| subkey|
+----+---------+---------+-------+
|key1|       45|       10|subkey1|
|key1|       45|       20|subkey2|
|key2|       70|       40|subkey2|
|key2|       70|       30|subkey1|
+----+---------+---------+-------+
```

I need convert the data frame to next:

```
result data (by pandas):
+-----+-----------+
|label|   features|
+-----+-----------+
|   45|[10.0,20.0]|
|   70|[30.0,40.0]|
+-----+-----------+
```

I can do the transformation with help of pandas:

```
def convert_to_flat_by_pandas(df):
    pandas_data_frame = df.toPandas()
    all_keys = pandas_data_frame['key'].unique()

    flat_values = []
    for key in all_keys:
        key_rows = pandas_data_frame.loc[pandas_data_frame['key'] == key]
        key_rows = key_rows.sort_values(by=['subkey'])

        parameter_values = key_rows['parameter']
        parameter_value = parameter_values.real[0]        

        key_reference_value = [reference_values for reference_values in key_rows['reference']]

        flat_values.append((parameter_value, key_reference_value))

    loaded_data = [(label, Vectors.dense(features)) for (label, features) in flat_values]
    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(loaded_data, ["label", "features"])

    return spark_df
```

Seems, I need use GroupBy, but I don't understand how sort and convert group (several rows) to single row.

Source of working sample (with help of pandas): https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/blob/master/pythonSamples/pysparkSamples/df_flat.py

With help of 2 answers I get 2 possible solutions:

**UPD1 Solution #1**

```
def convert_to_flat_by_sparkpy(df):
    subkeys = df.select("subkey").dropDuplicates().collect()
    subkeys = [s[0] for s in subkeys]
    print('subkeys: ', subkeys)
    assembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(subkeys).setOutputCol("features")
    spark_df = assembler.transform(df.groupBy("key", "parameter").pivot("subkey").agg(first(col("reference"))))    
    spark_df = spark_df.withColumnRenamed("parameter", "label")
    spark_df = spark_df.select("label", "features")
    return spark_df
```

**UPD1 Solution #2**

```
def convert_to_flat_by_sparkpy_v2(df):
    spark_df = df.orderBy("subkey")
    spark_df = spark_df.groupBy("key").agg(first(col("parameter")).alias("label"), collect_list("reference").alias("features"))
    spark_df = spark_df.select("label", "features")
    return spark_df
```

Comment: I need grouping in pyspark dataframe (not in pandas)

Comment: what is the type of `features`, can you show the output of `printSchema`?

Comment: schema: `schema of result's data frame:
root
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the limited sample data you have given, you can transform the data frame to wide format with the *subkey* as headers, and then use `VectorAssembler` to collect them as features:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first, col
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(["subkey1", "subkey2"]).setOutputCol("features")

assembler.transform(
    df.groupBy("key", "parameter").pivot("subkey").agg(first(col("reference")))
).show()
+----+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| key|parameter|subkey1|subkey2|   features|
+----+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
|key1|       45|     10|     20|[10.0,20.0]|
|key2|       70|     30|     40|[30.0,40.0]|
+----+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

---

Update for dynamic subkeys:

Say if you have a data frame like this:

```
df.show()
+----+---------+---------+-------+    
| key|parameter|reference| subkey|
+----+---------+---------+-------+
|key1|       45|       10|subkey1|
|key1|       45|       20|subkey2|
|key2|       70|       40|subkey2|
|key2|       70|       30|subkey1|
|key2|       70|       70|subkey3|
+----+---------+---------+-------+
```

Collect all unique sub keys firstly, and then use the *subkeys* to create the assembler:

```
subkeys = df.select("subkey").dropDuplicates().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
assembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(subkeys).setOutputCol("features")

assembler.transform(    
    df.groupBy("key", "parameter").pivot("subkey").agg(first(col("reference"))).na.fill(0)
).show()
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
| key|parameter|subkey1|subkey2|subkey3|        features|
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
|key1|       45|     10|     20|      0| [20.0,10.0,0.0]|
|key2|       70|     30|     40|     70|[40.0,30.0,70.0]|
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: It's a good sample, but I have 2 problems with my real code: I have random subkey values and I cannot create `Vectors.dense(df.features)`

Comment: Instead of `subkeys = df.select("subkey").dropDuplicates().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()` I added `subkeys = df.select("subkey").dropDuplicates().collect()
    subkeys = [s[0] for s in subkeys]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby and [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=function#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) function to obtain the output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy("parameter").agg(collect_list("reference").alias("features"))

df1.withColumnRenamed("parameter", "label")
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+
|parameter|features|
+---------+--------+
|       45|[10, 20]|
|       70|[40, 30]|
+---------+--------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this creates an array of features instead of a vector

Comment: I need sort "features" by subkey. Expected result: `[10, 20]` and `[30, 40]`

Comment: Values on column "parameter"  are not unique. I am afraid we cannot use the column in `groupBy`

Comment: I updated the suggested solution: looks short and good: `def convert_to_flat_by_sparkpy_v2(df):
    spark_df = df.orderBy("subkey")
    spark_df = spark_df.groupBy("key").agg(first(col("parameter")).alias("label"), collect_list("reference").alias("features"))
    spark_df = spark_df.select("label", "features")
    return spark_df`